# Merging records based on a priority field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with people's demographic information that has been compiled from multiple sources.  As a result, some people have duplicate records (based on their identifier) with differing data in other fields.  I've added a record_authority field that lists the row's priority based on its original source.  This is what it looks like:

```
record_authority    identifier    lastname    firstname    dob
1                   1234          Doe         William      1/1/2000
3                   1234          Doe         Bill         1/1/2000
2                   5678          Smith       Jane         NULL
3                   5678          Smith       Jane         1/1/1990
1                   9999          Brown       John         NULL
4                   9999          Brown       John         NULL
```

And here is what I'm trying to end up with.  NULL values should be replaced with the highest priority non-NULL value, when available.

```
identifier    lastname    firstname    dob
1234          Doe         William      1/1/2000
5678          Smith       Jane         1/1/1990
9999          Brown       John         NULL
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by identifier 
                                order by (case when record_authority is null then 2 else 1 end), record_authority asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Another uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.record_authority = (select min(t2.record_authority)
                            from t t2
                            where t2.identifier = t.identifier
                           );
```

Comment: Hi Gordon.  I should have mentioned that a lower record_authority value corresponds to higher priority--I think your queries have it reversed.  Also, it seems as if your queries are using the entire row, even when there are NULLs.  Is there are way to bring in the first non-NULL value (by priority) for a given field, as in the results table above?

Comment: @user56511 . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, which is clearer.  In this question, the returned data at least looks like it could come from a single row.  Use appropriate sample data and desired results.